# Magento Category with Specific Id

Tags: php, magento

I want to create categories in magento with a specified id not with what magento creates automatically.
Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Do you mean in code or through the admin?  Have you tried setting an ID in code yet?

Comment: through code @clockworkgeek

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the category ID number which looks something like this when you create a new category: "Category Name (ID: 123)", there is only two common ways to change this.

1) You will need to manually edit entries in the database. A properly written SQL statement should do the trick.

2) A safer way would be to export your categories (you may need an extension to do this) and edit the CSV file to your liking and import it back in. If you do this though and already have products linked to those categories, you will have to then export and edit your products to have the correct categories, otherwise you will have to one by one add products back to the new categories.

A Google search will bring up a few more answers and possible hacks but in short, your not meant to edit this ID. You haven't given us the context of why you would need to but as a developer who uses Magento I've never seen this need before? Then again everyone has unique situations.